# Error importing sdl2 in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdl, pysdl2

I have a file test.py which contains only the line "import sdl2". I am running Ubuntu and have installed libsdl2 from the official repos and installed pysdl2 from pip3. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sdl2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/sdl2/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .events import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/sdl2/events.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .keyboard import SDL_Keysym
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/sdl2/keyboard.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .video import SDL_Window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/sdl2/video.py", line 256, in <module>
    SDL_GL_ResetAttributes = _bind("SDL_GL_ResetAttributes")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/sdl2/dll.py", line 84, in bind_function
    (funcname, self._dll))
ValueError: could not find function 'SDL_GL_ResetAttributes' in <CDLL 'libSDL2-2.0.so.0', handle 1088720 at 7fdce18f5910>
```

My only thought is that possibly there's some version mismatch in packages? I couldn't find anything referencing this bug after a quick googling.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in pysdl2, which indicates that your SDL2 library version is not the latest one. (2.0.3). It has been fixed in a recent commit: https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/commits/03870c58615b115abf14b11056bbcd41652873c5